# How to connect to local clickhouse db form container?

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I started studying Docker and encountered some problems. I use Ubuntu and have local clickhouse database, also script in container, which suppose to write some data in db:

```
clickhouse-client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8123 --password=password --query "INSERT INTO some.table FORMAT CSV"
```

When i tyring run it, got:

```
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:8123)
```

It's work when i try to connect form DataGrip. Also i run docker with `--network="host"`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

clickhouse-client uses a port 9000 because it works over a native tcp protocol

jdbc uses an http port 8123

You can map ports from contanier to your host system (-p 127.0.0.1:8123:8123):

```
docker run  -d -p 127.0.0.1:8123:8123 -p 127.0.0.1:9000:9000 --name jdbc-test --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

[DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connectivity-problems.html#step-2-check-your-connection-properties) connects to ClickHouse using [HTTP](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/)-endpoint on 8123-port.

ClickHouse client uses [TCP](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/#command-line-client)-endpoint on port 9000.

It looks like need to publish port 9000:

```sh
docker run -d --name ch -p 8123:8123 -p 9000:9000 --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed port to native(tcp) port and its works fine

```
docker exec -it some-clickhouse-server bash
clickhouse-client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=9000

ClickHouse client version 24.1.1.2048 (official build).
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 24.1.1.
```